# Qt qwidget appearing and disappearing instantly

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I was writing a chat program with `Qt 5.9`. I finished the client-side program and started improving it. The first thing I did was making a new `Qwidget` (a secondary window) that would appear when pressing the connect button on my main window. Everything went fine, but when I tested and pressed the connect button on my main window, my secondary window appeared and disappeared instantly. How can I make my secondary window stay (not disappear) for the time the user presses the button (which is on the secondary window)?  Here is the code of both my windows :  ***main window.h (`fenClient.h`)***:

```
#ifndef FENCLIENT_H 

#define FENCLIENT_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <ui_fenclient.h>
#include <fenconnexion.h>

class FenClient : public QWidget, private Ui::FenClient
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FenClient();
    ~FenClient();

private slots:
    void on_boutonConnexion_clicked();
    void on_boutonEnvoyer_clicked();
    void on_message_returnPressed();
    void donneesRecues();
    void connecte();
    void deconnecte();
    void erreurSocket(QAbstractSocket::SocketError erreur);


private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    quint16 tailleMessage;


};

#endif // FENCLIENT_H

#include <fenclient.h>
```

***main window.cpp (fenClient.cpp)*** This is where the secondary window is created.

```
FenClient::FenClient()
{
    setupUi(this);


    socket = new QTcpSocket;
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(donneesRecues()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(connecte()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(deconnecte()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this,SLOT(erreurSocket(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    tailleMessage = 0;
}

void FenClient::on_boutonConnexion_clicked()
{
    listeMessages->append(tr("<em>Tentative de connexion en cours...</em>"));
    boutonConnexion->setEnabled(false);
    fenConnexion *fenetreCo = new fenConnexion; //this is where my secondary window is created
    fenetreCo->show(); 
    fenetreCo->activateWindow();
    fenetreCo->setParent(this);
    fenetreCo->echangerPseudo(pseudo->text());


    socket->abort();
    socket->connectToHost(serveurIP->text(),serveurPort->value());

}

void FenClient::on_boutonEnvoyer_clicked()
{
    if (message->text().isEmpty())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Veuillez écrire quelque chose","Pour éviter le spam, j'ai decidé d'empecher l'envoi de message vide. Veuillez écrire quelque chose...");
    }
    else if(pseudo->text() == "")
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Veuillez spécifier votre nom","Pour éviter l'anonimité, j'ai décidé d'obligé l'usage d'un pseudo.");
    }
    else
    {
        QByteArray paquet;
        QDataStream out(&paquet, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        QString messageAEnvoyer = tr("<strong>") + pseudo->text() + tr("</strong> : ") + message->text();

        out<<(quint16) 0;
        out<< messageAEnvoyer ;
        out.device()->seek(0);
        out << (quint16) (paquet.size() - sizeof(quint16));

        socket->write(paquet);

        message->clear();
        message->setFocus();
      }
}

void FenClient::on_message_returnPressed()
{
    on_boutonEnvoyer_clicked();
}

void FenClient::donneesRecues()
{
    QDataStream in(socket);

    if (tailleMessage==0)
    {
        if(socket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
        {return;}

        in >> tailleMessage;

    }
    if (socket->bytesAvailable() < tailleMessage)
    {return;}


    QString messageRecu;
    in >> messageRecu;

    listeMessages->append(messageRecu);

    tailleMessage = 0;
}

void FenClient::connecte()
{
    listeMessages->append(tr("<em>Connexion réussie</em>"));
    boutonConnexion->setEnabled(true);
    message->setEnabled(true);
}

void FenClient::deconnecte()
{
    listeMessages->append(tr("<em>Déconnecté!</em>"));
    message->setEnabled(false);
}
void FenClient::erreurSocket(QAbstractSocket::SocketError erreur)
{
    switch(erreur)
    {
        case QAbstractSocket::HostNotFoundError:
            listeMessages->append(tr("<em>ERREUR : le serveur n'a pas pu être trouvé. Vérifiez l'IP et le port.</em>"));
    break;
case QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError:
    listeMessages->append(tr("<em>ERREUR : le serveur a refusé la connexion. Vérifiez si le programme \"serveur\" a bien été lancé. Vérifiez aussi l'IP et le port.</em>"));
    break;
case QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError:
    listeMessages->append(tr("<em>ERREUR : le serveur a coupé la connexion.</em>"));
    break;
default:
    listeMessages->append(tr("<em>ERREUR : ") + socket->errorString() + tr("</em>"));
}

boutonConnexion->setEnabled(true);
}
FenClient::~FenClient()
{}
```

***secondary window.h (fenconnexion.h)***

```
    #ifndef FENCONNEXION_H
#define FENCONNEXION_H

#include <ui_fenconnexion.h>
#include <QtWidgets>


class fenConnexion : public QWidget, private Ui::Form
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    fenConnexion();
    QString pseudoUtilisateur;
    void echangerPseudo(QString pseudoAEchanger);
private slots :
    void checkPseudo();
private:
    QString pseudo;



};


#endif // FENCONNEXION_H
```

***secondary window.cpp (fenconnexion.cpp)***

```
    #include <fenconnexion.h>

fenConnexion::fenConnexion()
{   setupUi(this);


    connect(boutonInserer,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(checkPseudo()));
}

void fenConnexion::checkPseudo()
{
    pseudo=pseudoInsere->text();
    if (pseudo.isEmpty())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Probleme","Veuillez entre un pseudo conetenant au moins un caractere.");
    }
    else
    {
        pseudoUtilisateur=pseudo;
        pseudoInsere->clear();
        pseudo.clear();
        this->close();
    }
}
void fenConnexion::echangerPseudo(QString pseudoAEchanger)
{
    pseudoAEchanger.clear();
    pseudoAEchanger = pseudoUtilisateur;
}
```

I feel like I've made a very simple error, but as I haven't used Qt in over 6 months, I don't seem to find it.

Comment: you can make "fenConnexion *fenetreCo" as a member of class may be some how its going "out of scope" which leads to destruction of secondry window

Comment: @Sourabh Do you mean putting "fenconnexion *fenetreCo;" in my main window .h file and the putting "fenetreCo = new fenconnexion" in my mainwindow.cpp file? If yes I have just tried it and it doesn't work...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on line `this->close();` and see whether it's called or not.

Comment: Why do you show the window *before* setting it up correctly (i.e. setting its parent, etc.)? Is the window modal or not? Checking the Qt documentation for `show` and `setVisible(bool)` didn't make that immediately clear to me. (It's been a while since I've used Qt, too.) BTW, posting non-English code may make help more difficult to come by; I'm struggling to understand your code myself.

Comment: @ray Okay so maybe this seemed to be the preoblem.I just tried to change the order (first setting its parent, etc...) and it worked. Thank you very much and sorry for this evident mistake.

Comment: @ray Just saw it and marked as an answer. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you've set up the window properly before trying to show it.

```
fenConnexion *fenetreCo = new fenConnexion;
fenetreCo->show(); 
fenetreCo->activateWindow();
fenetreCo->setParent(this);
```

Set the parent of the window before invoking `show` on it. That makes the window `this`' child, which means that it's `this`' responsibility to manage its life-cycle.